# Same font except its weight seems different on different browsers

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser

The text is correctly displayed in Chrome. I want it to display this way in all browsers. How can I do this?

I was able to fix this in Safari with `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`

Chrome:
[image: Chrome]

Firefox:
[image: Firefox]

```css
h1 {
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16pt;
    color: #444444;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hi, my name</h1>
```

And a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jnxQ8/1/

Comment: Generally speaking, the different browsers all handle their own text rendering. If you Google this, you will see a lot of results about browser rendering. Unless there is something quirky in your CSS, chance are you are at the mercy of the different rendering enginers for each associated browser.

Comment: It are screenshot's people. I solved it in Safari with `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` Now for firefox?

Comment: isnt that css3 ? font smothing ?

Comment: Definitely the Webkit Font Smoothing declaration in Chrome. It only affects particular fonts, this site posted about it in 2010. http://ilikekillnerds.com/2010/12/a-solution-to-stop-font-face-fonts-looking-bold-on-mac-browsers/

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Be sure the font is the same for all browsers. If it is the same font, then the problem has **no solution** using **cross-browser CSS**.

Because every browser has its own font rendering engine, they are all different. They can also differ in later versions, or across different OS's.

**UPDATE**: For those who do not understand the browser and OS font rendering differences, [read this](http://szafranek.net/works/articles/font-smoothing-explained/) and [this](http://maxvoltar.com/archive/-webkit-font-smoothing).

However, the difference is not even noticeable by most people, and users accept that. Forget pixel-perfect cross-browser design, unless you are:

1. Trying to turn-off the subpixel rendering by CSS (not all browsers allow that and the text may be ugly...)
2. Using images (resources are demanding and hard to maintain)
3. Replacing Flash (need some programming and doesn't work on iOS)

---

**UPDATE**: I checked the example page. Tuning the kerning by text-rendering should help:

```
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
```

More references here:

1. Part of the font-rendering is controlled by [`font-smoothing`](http://www.usabilitypost.com/2010/08/26/font-smoothing/) (as mentioned) and another part is [`text-rendering`](http://www.aestheticallyloyal.com/public/optimize-legibility/). Tuning these  properties may help as their default values are not the same across browsers.
2. For Chrome, if this is still not displaying OK for you, try this [text-shadow hack](http://eligrey.com/blog/post/better-font-smoothing-in-google-chrome-on-windows). It should improve your Chrome font rendering, especially in Windows. However, text-shadow will go mad under Windows XP. Be careful.

Comment: I don't understand why Chrome and Safari render differently: they're both WebKit-based.

Comment: Yeah, but Chrome apparantly does automatically apply `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;' and Safari doesn't?

Comment: chrome and safari is similar but not the same browser: they shared same base, webkit, but many platform-specific components and css modules are different - safari support more css3 property than chrome. And font-rendering is quite platform-specific.

Comment: @ChrisW - Safari has it's own font rendering engine to give a similar experience as on OSX. Thus the '-webkit-font-smoothing' property will only appear to work on Safari (under Windows). And yet another variable is, you can modify the anti-aliasing in the browser Preferences.

Comment: I actually had a problem on two different pages of the same site, with the same CSS applied, rendering different results. The ``font-smoothing: antialiased;`` worked wonders for me.

Comment: I am still facing problem with Safari - too bold and chrome normal bold. Please give me proper solution. I am using Mac

Answer (score 19):

In order to best standardise your @font-face embedded fonts across browsers try including the below inside your @font-face declaration or on your body font styling:

```
speak: none;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-variant: normal;
text-transform: none;
line-height: 1;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

At present there looks to be no universal fix across all platforms and browser builds. As stated frequently all browsers/OS have different text rendering engines.

Answer (score 15):

There's some great information about this here:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=857142

Still experimenting but so far a minimally invasive solution, aimed only at FF is:

```
body {
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Try `-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;`

Answer (score 6):

I collected and tested discussed solutions:

Windows10 Prof x64:

```
* FireFox v.56.0 x32 
* Opera v.49.0
* Google Chrome v.61.0.3163.100 x64-bit
```

macOs X Serra v.10.12.6 Mac mini (Mid 2010):

```
* Safari v.10.1.2(12603.3.8)
* FireFox v.57.0 Quantum
* Opera v49.0
```

Semi (still micro fat in Safari) solved fatty fonts:

```
text-transform: none; // mac ff fix
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; // safari mac nicer
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; // fix fatty ff on mac
```

Have no visual effect

```
line-height: 1;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; 
speak: none;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
```

Wrong visual effect:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased !important; //more fatty in safari
text-rendering: geometricPrecision !important; //more fatty in safari
```

do not forget to set !important when testing or be sure that your style is not overridden

Comment: How would text-transform fix/break anything?

Answer (score 3):

I have many sites with this issue & **finally found a fix** to firefox fonts being thicker than chrome.

You need this line next to your -webkit fix `-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;`

```
body{
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using "points" for font-size on a screen is a good idea. Try using px or em on font-size.

From [W3C](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/font-size):

> Do not specify the font-size in pt,
>   or other absolute length units. They
>   render inconsistently across platforms
>   and can't be resized by the User Agent
>   (e.g browser).

Comment: But It has nothing to do with the boldness of the font?

Comment: boldness is controlled by font-smoothing (and the subpixel technique by OS and browser rendering engine) most.

Comment: ON chrome is the same its start on Chrome 20 , chrome 17 whose OK

Answer (score -2):

Try `text-rendering: geometricPrecision;`.

Different from `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;`, it takes care of kerning problems when scaling fonts, while the last enables kerning and ligatures.