# Problem in firefox vs chrome with bold text and double borders

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts, bold

I'm working on a site and I have some problems that I hope you guys can help me with :)

1. If I put bold on my text in the menu it looks too bold in Firefox :S, but it looks fine in Chrome.
2. In Firefox the double border on the #content container is outside of the shadow effect :S, but looks good in Chrome.

[Screen shot](http://d.pr/hWHO) on Mac Firefox 5.0.1 and Chrome 13.0.782.112:

[This](http://sijdesign.dk/rap/) is my project.

I hope some one can help me out with this.

If you have something I better I can do, I will be glad to hear that too :)

Comment: I honestly can't see the difference. What version of firefox? what version of chrome?

Comment: http://d.pr/qmC9 @rikudo sennin

Comment: same as mine. Can't see the difference. Consider posing screenshots of your problem.

Comment: http://d.pr/hWHO @Rikudo

Comment: Actually, it's a known bug. It's weird that I can't retrace the problem, however just for future reference, consider [this](http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/) website.

Comment: @rikudo Sure, but you can try.

Comment: @eskimoblood actually I am trying, I tried changing fonts, making the text bolder/not, I just can't retrace it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first issue regarding `bold` font looking different between the browsers is just because of the way browsers render text differently. There is nothing you can do about it, unless you go the horrible route of using images instead.

Your second issue is not about the `border` but rather the `outline`. It is caused because of the way Firefox interprets the `outline` when `box-shadow` is applied. It applies it outside of the shadow instead.

You can put the code below in your css to target Firefox and bring the outline back in:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    #content{
        outline-offset: -11px;
    }
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/n8bet/

Comment: -1 for using the same ID twice on your example! Shame on you!!

Comment: I've seen the example change (edit your post slightly so that I can remove the -1 :D)

Answer (score 1):

@1: There differences in font rendering in every browser. You can try numeric values instead of simply bold to narrow the results ( http://clagnut.com/blog/2228/ ). Also read the answer on this SO entry: [Same font except its weight seems different on different browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082632/same-font-yet-its-weight-seems-different-on-different-browsers)

@2: remove this line from #content css:

```
outline: 1px solid #B9BDBE;
```