# urdu fonts difference in chrome and firefox

Tags: asp.net, css

i am using narkisim font in html for urdu. In google chrome it is looking different then firefox.

```
font-family:Narkisim;
```

Its the font family setting.

Any suggestions.

Comment: possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/a/5082824/2040375

Comment: I didnt found the thread. Sorry

Comment: Yes. Its relevant but it wasnt about urdu font. Also there is no solutions

Comment: what difference is between showing text with this font in browsers? only size is different? can you show me?

Comment: ahp.com.pk, open it with firefox and google chrome

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30133/discussion-between-majidgeek-and-great-majestics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shown on my system :

[image]

so I think FireFox can not find this font on system and show text with default font.

Comment: Seems the solution was too easy :)