# Bold fonts gets very wide in some browsers

Tags: html, css

I know that browsers render fonts differently especially bold fonts look different in all browsers unless `font-weigh` is set to `normal` but this stops us using bold fonts.

When I apply `font-weight: bold;` to `#default_menu` element, menu output gets very wide in some browsers compared to some others and it is a bit too much to be hones, not like 1 or 2 px.

Is there any chance to solve this issue or at least make it better?

Thanks

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/b2L5w/)

[image]

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#nogo" title="HOME">HOME</a></li>
    <li class="main_menu_seperator">|</li>
    <li><a href="#nogo" title="HOW IT WORKS">HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
    <li class="main_menu_seperator">|</li>
    <li><a href="#nogo" title="PARTNERS">PARTNERS</a></li>
    <li class="main_menu_seperator">|</li>
    <li><a href="#nogo" title="BLOG">BLOG</a></li>
    <li class="main_menu_seperator">|</li>
    <li><a href="#nogo" title="CONTACT US">CONTACT US</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#default_menu
{
    font-weight: normal;
}
#default_menu
{
    font-size: 16px;
}
#default_menu ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#default_menu li
{
    display: inline;
}
.main_menu_seperator
{
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
```

Comment: `some browser` must have their name

Comment: "...gets very wide in some browsers compared to some others..." Which browsers?

Comment: OPEN SANS: http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans

Comment: Wider in FF and Opera. Fine in Google.

Comment: I'll add images, wait for a second please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Same font yet its weight seems different on different browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082632/same-font-yet-its-weight-seems-different-on-different-browsers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following thread.

I hope this is your issue

[Same font except its weight seems different on different browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082632/same-font-yet-its-weight-seems-different-on-different-browsers)

Comment: I read this before but I though there could be a solution since but obviously not. Thanks

Comment: @MadMax, intentionally posting a duplicate, without even referring to an old question yoy’ve read, is not constructive. To help people find answers, we should improve answers to existing questions, instead of spawning copies of a question with different sets of answers.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

please try  if you want normal font please write `font-weight:100;` and if you want bold font please use `font-weight:600;`

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b2L5w/1/)**

**css**

if you want `font-weight:normal` `not bold` use below `selector`;

```
#default_menu
    {
       font-weight:100;/* normal font*/
       font-size: 16px; /*bold font*/
    }
```

OR

if you want to `font-weight:bold` please use below `selector`

```
#default_menu
{
font-weight:600;
font-size:16px;
}
```

Comment: Although nothing changed, how do I benefit from using 600/100 instead of bold/normal?

Comment: I know I read it on W3Schools but do I benefit when I use numbers instead of bold, normal etc? Also, 400 is the same as normal, and 700 is the same as bold...

Comment: @MadMax try 500,600 ?

Answer (score 0):

The font depends on the browser and operating system.

Check [**this**](http://szafranek.net/works/articles/font-smoothing-explained/)

font-weight property

```
font-weight: 400 /* is normal, not 100 */
font-weight: 700 /* is bold, not 600. */
```