# Pixel sizes differ between browsers

Tags: html, css

If you got to http://www.claymation.azularis.com/work and look at the search bar, there is a text box and a search button.  Depending on which browser you look at it, the text box will be either same height as the button or smaller.  I am trying to figure out how to make them even size across all browsers.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Just to give example, in Firefox when I use Firebug to measure size of the submit button it says: 19 px.  When I measure in chrome, it says 16px.   I tried setting min-height: 19px; but chrome still renders it as 16 pixels.

Comment: welcome to Browser Wars III. The only remedy to most differences is adding conditional styles to target specific browsers... or simply do not care.

Comment: maybe the problem is in your font browser display it differently. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082632/same-font-yet-its-weight-seems-different-on-different-browsers

Comment: Chrome on mac shows 19px. If you add a line-height for your text, the display will be more consistent across browsers. Try adding: line-height: 1.2em;

Comment: Yeah I was testing with line height but that didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this prefixes:

```
.buttonHeight
{
   height: 19px; // probably your code
   -webkit-height:19px; // for chrome and safari
   -o-height:19px; // for opera
   -moz-height:19px; // for firefox
}
```

For IE you can just pray...

Comment: Funny enough, that had no effect

Comment: it turns out the border was a problem, for some reason chrome was creating a border and IE would not, so when I set border:none then it all started matching up.

Comment: IE lower than 10 doesent support css in total, and css3 I dont wanna mention. Just make check if visitors using IE. If they using IE just give them a notification like this http://postimg.org/image/lk0m5eqlh/ and give them links to download chrome, firefox, safari or opera and keep calm and forget IE.