# font weight is thicker in ie 11 than chrome and firefox

Tags: css, internet-explorer

hi guys on ie 11 http://csdm4.com/design-build/ the heading 'Design build' is much thicker than chrome, any idea how could i fix it. I tried different font weight for it but it is still not working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082632/same-font-yet-its-weight-seems-different-on-different-browsers

Comment: different browsers render fonts differently you shouldn't *fix* it. It's not broken, that's just how it is.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
body{
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```