# how to properly include google font for css to use?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I am using this Font right now:

https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Roboto

According to the guide I'll just have to include a link like this

And I've tried that... it worked but my problem is:

The output from Firefox and Chrome is different...

Chrome:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

As you can observed from the two pictures... Firefox is displaying it right and smooth..

What am I missing here? Display from chrome is not that good.. any help would be much appreciated..

Comment: There is even tutorial how to include them in Google Fonts.

Comment: yeah i followed that.. and it worked.. but the display is not that good..pls read first..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5082824/3599549, it may help.

Comment: @JohnRayPaulin I have edited my answer. Any chance this solved your issue?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the default font of your browser. You did not specify a `font-weight` in the style. If you add `font-weight: 300;` in the style, you should see the same thing.

**Edit** I found the styles you added in Google font cause the issue. If you only add `300` and `300 italic` it will give a better result. http://jsfiddle.net/5mnq06km/5/

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
}
b {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<p>
  Some <b>Text</b>
</p>
```

Comment: This won't always work. Sometimes it just depends on the browsers rendering.

Comment: That is true. However if you ensure all the styles are the same over all browsers, you make the chance of different results smallest.

Answer (score 0):

Define weight of the font in your body so all browsers will handle it the same.

Font-weight:300;

Comment: tried this.. doesn't work..

Comment: Try this post guy explained everything:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082632/same-font-yet-its-weight-seems-different-on-different-browsers