# "Source Sans Pro" font-weight: 400 displays bolder than 600 on Chrome, Safari and Firefox

Tags: css, webfonts, google-font-api

It seems the font weight: 400 is bolder than 600. Does this happen only to me? On my Mac Book Pro, it displays the same on Chrome, Safari and Firefox. So, I guess it is not a browser related issue.

https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Source+Sans+Pro

What is the best solution for this? Using font weight:600 rather than 400 for a normal font weight? I don't know how to report the issue to Google.

Comment: might help! [stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082632/same-font-yet-its-weight-seems-different-on-different-browsers)

Comment: Thank you yjs. For this issue, both webkit (Chrome/Safari) and moziila (Firefox) display the same issue. So, the cross browser font rendering is not the case. But I appreciate it.

Comment: It's likely this is an issue with your code, not the font itself. Have a look at this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u1sjhufd/)**; on my machine, on all three browsers you mentioned the `font-weight` displays properly.

Comment: Thank you Quoid! You're right. For some reason, the browsers on my laptop display the font weight incorrectly even on your fiddle link. But I can see them properly when I looked at it on an online cross browser platform. I appreciate it.

Comment: @shinyatk glad to help, i've put an answer up so you can marked this as resolved

Comment: @Quiod I marked yours as resolved. I still need to figure out why on my machine shows incorrect font rendering. But you helped me to find out the problem was my machine not universal. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is likely an issue with your machine (happens to the best of us).

Take a look at **[this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u1sjhufd/)** on a different machine (I've personally verified `font-weight` changes on multiple browsers); you *will* see the differences.

Answer (score 1):

Now I figured out why this happened. As @Quiod gave me a tip that the issue was on my machine not google's fault (of course). The reason was I "Synced fonts" with "Source Sans Pro Bold" on Adobe Typekit. When I unsynced it, the font displays properly. If the same things happen on the other fonts, you might need to uninstall your local fonts. Then the problem goes away. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adobe has a font with the same "Source Sans Pro" name which confuses most browsers except for Internet Explorer. You can just delete it from the Control Panel/Fonts folder, no reboot necessary.