# Safari font is rendering wrong

Tags: html, css, fonts, safari

I am using Google's Open Sans Font on my website.
Firefox and Chrome display the font in the right way, but Safari is not.
I tried all `-webkit-font-smoothing`options out, but it seems that is only fix it on OS X.

[4-Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu9KX.jpg) -> On the top side of the image is my own website

```
<select class="Open-Sans-normal-400">
   <option>EUW</option>
</select>
```

and on the bottom side the same font, but on [Googles Font Website](https://www.google.com/fonts)

If you need more informations, just tell me. I'll add them.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a fix for this which worked for me with Safari on IOS and Macs.

When browsers cant find a bold version, they try to copy it which may vary in the rendering result.

You can try to disable it by adding: this CSS:

```
font-synthesis: none
```

Otherwise you can try setting the font-weight manually ie.

```
font-weight: 400
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
* {
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; 
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; 
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Source: [Same font except its weight seems different on different browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082632/same-font-yet-its-weight-seems-different-on-different-browsers)

Comment: Your code or your source did not help me, to get the font in safari look like the normal 400 weight. :/

Comment: Did you consider that it is not a lighter font but a lighter rendering due to the fact that you use it on a dark background? Can you test this by changing the colors to black on white?

Comment: White on Black AND Black on White does look like its lighted as hell.    

But when I use `_::-moz-svg-foreign-content, :root body {-webkit-text-stroke: 0.5px;}` it looks like it should, but this is not a good solution.