# Why same fonts looks blurred in Google Chrome and Safari compare to Firefox?

Tags: css, browser, fonts

I am developing site using [Drupal CMS](https://www.drupal.org/). To check the look and feel I often check in firefox, Chrome and Safari. But I always find that the fonts looks deem and blurred in Chrome and safari compare to Firefox as you can see in following images.

Is there any solution for that? Thanks.

**Chrome: Version 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit)**

> [image]

**Sarafi: Version 9.1.2 (11601.7.7)**

> [image]

**Firefox: 48.0**

> [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Same font yet its weight seems different on different browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082632/same-font-yet-its-weight-seems-different-on-different-browsers)

Comment: @Juhana Thanks for the link, looking into.