# "pt" sizes appearing inconsistent when printing from Chrome vs. Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing, safari, media-queries

I am working on a project that involves stylized versions of pages for print. I have specs from a designer that includes font sizes and dimensions in points. I develop in Chrome, and I can get a near perfect layout using point values. When I try printing from Safari, everything appears slightly larger, maybe 5-10%. This causes serious layout issues when things stop fitting on the page. I can't fathom this because points are supposed to be consistent for print media. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5082632/3597276

Comment: Can you point to a webpage where this happens?

Answer (score -1):

look for your [viewport](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/fundamentals/set-the-viewport).
and than you can look for the [conversion units](https://webkit.org/blog/57/css-units/).