# how to make the css font-weight consistent across browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, fonts, cross-browser

I am using a custom font that I implemented into my website using the @font-face css selector and provided the different formats of the fonts for the different browsers, up to this point firefox, chrome IE11 and opera render the font approximatly the same.

but when it comes to giving a `font-weight: 900`; Only Chrome succedes in rendering a bold enough font,
firefox and IE rendering is close to what chrome renders at 500 or 600

is there a work around to acheive the same result in the other browsers without having to implement a bolded version of the font in all different formats ???

[firefox rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDzzT.png)

[chrome rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxr3z.png)

Comment: related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082632/same-font-except-its-weight-seems-different-on-different-browsers

Answer (score 0):

The best way to keep font weights consistent is making sure that font comes with a bold weight font file. If your font files don't come with your desired weight then the Browser & OS will try to manually style the font which results in, as you've seen, different rendering.