# Google web font Montserrat issue on Firefox - Bold

Tags: css, firefox, fonts, google-webfonts

I have a joomla site and i tried to use the font "Montserrat" from google on some classes.

The font looks good on chrome and I.E., but looks bold or bolder on firefox.

The css that i tried

```
p
{
     font-weight: normal;
}

p
{
     font-weight: 400;
}
```

I found a thousand topics on internet, no solution.

Comment: Did you try the suggestions in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082632/same-font-except-its-weight-seems-different-on-different-browsers

Comment: Yes. Dont Works.

Comment: The issue has been solved in firefox 101.0.1, still present in 101.0.

Comment: Today I noticed it affecting v.112.0.1 (64bit windows). It's hit & miss as usual. Windows 7 Firefox machines almost always display font "too light". Some Win 10/11 machines with FFox as well display same way. Have found no common factor. If it's a Goolge Font problem (as I have read other places), why this hit and miss problem? Same font and specs, right?

Comment: Regarding my last comment - this was in regards to it displaying incorrect weight. (Too light - not too bold as in OP question). But same font. This bug is closest to the problem I see = https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1772370 but, it's closed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe help:

```
html {
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
body {
  font-weight: 500;
}


/* and browser specific rule at the bottom */
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  body {
    font-weight: lighter !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this:

CSS pre-processor is removing quotation marks

...then I've found out that:
CSS processor (cssnano) in our React app is removing quotation marks

So my font is loading locally from my computer, not from Google's servers.
This causes a different font file in Firefox than in Chrome.

Check this out: https://github.com/cssnano/cssnano/issues/177