# font-weight not applied properly on Chrome and Firefox, but works on Safari

Tags: css, fonts

I am currently using **'Avelir Next'** font on my website (Shopify store to be exact), and I used `font-weight: 300` and `font-weight: 400` styling, which translates perfectly on Safari, but not on Chrome and Firefox.

Safari: [screenshot](https://screenshot.click/19-11-mh5xx-uzg33.png)

Chrome and Firefox: [screenshot](https://screenshot.click/19-11-5ma2s-3yg4x.png)

My question is, why is this an issue with Chrome and Firefox, but not on Safari? Is this something to do with Chrome/Firefox? Or this something to do with how the font is uploaded on Shopify's end? Or is it something that I did, or need to add in the styling? I've tried adding `-webkit-font-smoothing-` but that doesn't help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082632/same-font-except-its-weight-seems-different-on-different-browsers does this help